# ¿Cómo heredar clase de objeto y reescribir un método correctamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, object, herencia

#### Estoy intentando heredar la clase "Root" y modificar el método "get_request", no me ha funcionado. ¿Cómo va a hacer esto?

```
class Root(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._loaded = False

    def get_request(self, httprequest):

        if httprequest.args.get('jsonp'):
            return JsonRequest(httprequest)

        if httprequest.mimetype in ("application/json", "application/json-rpc"):
             return JsonRequest(httprequest)

        else:
            return HttpRequest(httprequest)
```

#### lo que espero es heredar la clase Root y colocar un nuevo método "get_request"

```
class InheritRoot(Root):

    def __init__(self):
        Root.__init__(self)

    def get_request(self, httprequest):

        if "my new validation here":
            return ("my new value here")

        if httprequest.args.get('jsonp'):
            return JsonRequest(httprequest)

        if httprequest.mimetype in ("application/json", "application/json-rpc"):
            return JsonRequest(httprequest)

        else:
            return HttpRequest(httprequest)
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué es lo que no te ha funcionado?, ¿te arroja algún error?

Comment: Necesito heredar el objeto Root y modificar la funcion get_request. lo que e intentado no ha funcionado

Comment: @YanChirino Pero no has respondido a qué no te ha funcionado. El código que has puesto es la forma correcta de hacerlo, pero según parece no funciona como esperas. ¿Qué esperas y qué obtienes?

Comment: el programa cuando se ejecuta pasa por la funcion get_request de la clase Root .... Lo que necesito es heredar la clase Root y que la ejecucion pase por el "get_request" que defino en la nueva clase "InheritRoot" inhabilitando el get_request de la clase Root.

Comment: Lo único que tienes que hacer es reemplazar en tu código la parte en donde instancias `Root` y cambiarlo por `InheritRoot`. No sé exactamente a qué te refieres. Actualiza tu pregunta e incluye la parte de tu código en la cual estás usando las clases.

Comment: es un programa muy grande, no puedo editar la fuente, solo puedo heredar

Comment: @YanChirino dices "_Lo que necesito es heredar la clase Root y que la ejecucion pase por el "get_request" que defino en la nueva clase "InheritRoot" inhabilitando el get_request de la clase Root_". Pues eso precisamente es lo que hace la herencia! ¿Será que has olvidado cambiar la creación del objeto? Debes instanciarlo de la clase `InheritRoot()`, en vez de `Root()` ¿O será que lo que quieres hacer es un _monkey patch_? (cambiar el comportamiento de tu programa sin tocarlo, y que los objetos de tipo `Root` tengan el nuevo comportamiento)

Comment: @abulafia ... exactamente eso es lo que necesito """monkey patch""" (cambiar el comportamiento de tu programa sin tocarlo, y que los objetos de tipo Root tengan el nuevo comportamiento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que lo que quieres es poder cambiar de algún modo el comportamiento de la clase `Root`, pues (según entiendo) el código que tienes hace uso de esa clase y quieres cambiar su comportamiento, y por lo que sea no puedes tocar ese código.

Si pudieras modificar el código, podrías seguir el enfoque que has intentado, esto es, importar la clase `Root`, crear una nueva clase que herede de ella (`InheritRoot`) y sobrecargue uno de sus métodos. Pero, claro, las variables afectadas serían aquellas instanciadas así: `variable = InheritRoot()`, pero no afectará a las instanciadas así `variable = Root()`.

Lo que necesitas se denomina [*monkey patching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) y en Python es fácil de hacer gracias a que todo es dinámico y redefinible.

Sería como sigue:

```
from modulo_que_define_Root import Root

def nueva_get_request(self, httprequest):
    # Implementación de esta función
    # de acuerdo con tus necesidades

Root.get_request = nueva_get_request

# Resto del código que usa  Root
```

Fíjate en la trampa. Definimos una función "normal y corriente" (`nueva_get_request()`). El hecho de que su primer parámetro se llame `self` puede ser chocante, pero no tiene nada de particular, ya que `self` no es palabra reservada. Podemos llamar a nuestros parámetros como queramos.

El truco viene en la asignación `Root.get_request = nueva_get_request`, que accede a la clase `Root` para sustituir su método `get_request` por el nuevo que hemos preparado. Gracias a que en python *las clases también son objetos*, son dinámicas y podemos modificar sus elementos, entre ellos sus métodos.

Una variable instanciada como `Root()` a partir de aqui tendrá su comportamiento alterado, ya que ejecutará nuestra nueva función cuando quiera ejecutar `Root.get_request`. Este *monkey patching* afectará incluso a las clases derivadas de `Root` (si las hubiere) que no sobrecarguen esta función, ya que la que herederán será nuestra versión modificada.

Comment: Excelente, funciona para lo que estoy haciendo. Gracias!!